# Как занести в таблицу базы данных SQLite ключ шифрования?

Tags: python, sqlite, decrypt

Нужно создать таблицу, в которой были бы колонки с логином, паролем и ключем шифрования. При создании таблицы таким образом, как приведено на отрывке кода ниже возникает ошибка формата:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "'rNM3EGbZEK3UFaaSPOPlYdgkriznvWpN_T1RaEtfqBU='": syntax error
```

Как это можно исправить?

```
text = b"Text for encrypt"

cipher_key = Fernet.generate_key()
cipher = Fernet(cipher_key)

encrypted_text = cipher.encrypt(text)
decrypted_text = cipher.decrypt(encrypted_text)

print(cipher_key)
print(decrypted_text)

conn = sqlite3.connect("users.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

valu1 = "aleksei"
valu2 = 123456
valu3 = cipher_key

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_data (Login text, 
                                                         Password int,
                                                         Cipher_Key text);""")
cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO users_data (Login, 
                                           Password, 
                                           Cipher_Key) 
                                           VALUES 
                                           ({valu1},
                                            {valu2},
                                            {valu3});""")
```

Comment: Почитайте документацию sqlite3, подставлять переменные через такое форматирование строк это абсолютно неправильно и вообще опасно

Answer (score 0):

Используйте плейсхолдеры (`placeholder` в документации: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).
И не забывайте про `commit` и `close`.

Ваш код заработает с такими исправлениями:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users_data (Login,  Password, Cipher_Key) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
                    (valu1, valu2, valu3 ))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```